# Reading , Writing unreadable file stream to save in database

Tags: java

I need to write a file stream to database. The file content must be readable only through

the program. Manual open file should not display the readable content. I decided to use

ObjectOutput stream as it is the binary writing mechanism in java. But I can see the string

content when I open the file.

Writing to stream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
os.writeObject("HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII HOW ARE YOU");
```

The created content is look like

```
¬í t #HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII HOW ARE YOU
```

How to get complete binary stream output?

Comment: Have you tried just writing the resulting `byte` array?

Comment: yes I tried os.writeObject("HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII HOW ARE YOU".getBytes());. It produces more byte content + string                  ¬í ur [B¬óøTà  xp   #HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII HOW ARE YOU

Comment: Now, just write the result byte array itself, without the `ObjectOutputStream`...

Comment: Writing to baos.write("HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII HOW ARE                                   HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII HOW ARE YOUPK    YþD               xx

Comment: You need to decide how much security you want and what you are willing to invest. Obfuscation: apply an easily reversible transformation that prevents someone from reading the text unless they expend a little effort. Example: rot13 or base64 encode the data. Encryption: apply a standard secure encryption method (DES, BlowFish, etc).  This method involves learning the APIs and managing the encryption keys, but without those keys NOBODY can read the data.  Note: Key management is the hardest part of encrypting data.

Answer (score 1):

> The file content must be readable only through the program. Manual open file should not display the readable content.

So you need some security.

> I decided to use ObjectOutput stream as it is the binary writing mechanism in java.

That's (a) a *non sequitur,* and (b) security by obscurity: i.e. it is no security at all.

You should use encryption.

Comment: I agree with you but it shows the string that the issue apart from the binary value.              ¬í t #HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII HOW ARE YOU

Comment: That's because using what you consider a 'binary format' doesn't do what you think it does. 'Binary' isn't encryption, or obfuscation, of any kind. Use something that's actually going to work.